# Is returning a calculated boolean pythonic or I should use traditional if/else?

Tags: python

I was wondering which of the following examples is more accepted within the Python community:

1.

```
return any(host[0].endswith(bot_hosts) for bot_hosts in bot_hosts)
```

2.

```
if any(host[0].endswith(bot_hosts) for bot_hosts in bot_hosts):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Or maybe something else?

Please advise.

Comment: Version 1 definitely (if the end result is always a boolean `return`) - but I think your loop var should be called `bot_host` - not be the same name as your source :)

Comment: as far as it matters I agree with Jon

Comment: `if somebooleantest: return True` is never more pythonic; just return `somebooleantest`.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the catch. It was actually a typo, I am surprised it was working :)

Comment: @JonClements: actually `for x in x` works just fine, although it's definitely a bad idea.

Comment: @thg435 It "works", but in cases of a list-comp (for eg) (in the 2.x series - it's leaked to the outer namespace) - so definitely a bad idea :), see: https://gist.github.com/4545525 as an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In your example case: `str.endswith` takes tuple as an argument. Overall, as a design pattern use the first version (check the reasoning @Ben's answer).
That is `any(host[0].endswith(bot_host) for bot_host in bot_hosts)` is the same as:*

```
host[0].endswith(bot_hosts) #if bot_hosts is a tuple
                            #if bot_hosts in not a tuple add tuple(bot_hosts)
```

*Example:*

```
In [1]: suffs = ('a','b','d')

In [2]: 'asd'.endswith(suffs)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: 'asap'.endswith(suffs)
Out[3]: False
```

Comment: Given the OPs code - yes - great way of doing this - not sure it answers the question - but then, not sure the question's answerable anyway :)

Comment: @JonClements -- Yes, it seemed to me, that the overall design pattern was already made pretty clear :)

Answer (score 4):

```
if <anything>:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

is usually extremely pointless. `<anything>` has to return something truthy or falsey anyway, so just return that.

The only reason you would want to do this is if you want to make sure that you're returning only `True` or `False`, because your `<anything>` might be returning some other object. For example, maybe it might return a large object, which you no longer care about after checking that it was there, so you'd rather not return a reference to it that might prevent its memory from being reclaimed. Or maybe your `<anything>` might be returning an object or `None`, and while `None` is falsey you're concerned that later code will be using `is not None` tests, and you want the false path to not be counted as `None`.

Even then (as poke has pointed out in the comment), you can use `bool(<anything>)` to get a value that is guaranteed to be `True` or `False` based on the truthiness of `<anything>`, so there's never a good reason to use an `if` statement that immediately returns either `True` or `False`.

In your case, `any` always returns `True` or `False`. So you literally have a value that is either `True` or `False`, checking which one it is, and then returning `True` if it was `True` and returning `False` if it was `False`.

Comment: If `<anything>` is not a bool, return `bool(<anything>)`.

Answer (score 1):

The second version is completely out, that's like comparing a boolean value to True in order to check if it's true. What I personally would do is to use a loop instead, i.e. to separate the iteration part from the part that is performed on each element, in the hope of making this a bit easier to read.